# How to remove JSON object based on id from array type script

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an cart array into which I am pushing the elements like:

```
 cart = [];
 this.cart.push(item);
```

I also want to delete the element from this `cart[]` array based on id, the objects structure looks like:

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people?1",
        author: "Windward",
        handle: "@windwardstudios",
        body: "Looking for a better company reporting or docgen app?",
        totalLikes: 0,
        iLike: false
    },
    {
        id:2,
        imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people?1",
        author: "Windward",
        handle: "@windwardstudios",
        body: "Looking for a better company reporting or docgen app?",
        totalLikes: 0,
        iLike: false
    }
]
```

I'm doing the `pop` operation to remove the object that is added to array, but unfortunately this is removing the last inserted item. Which I don't want.

```
this.cart.pop();
```

How can I do this in typescript?

Comment: There is no JSON in this question. JSON is a set of rules to format a string so it can be parsed as an object. The objects themselves are just _objects_.

Comment: `var jsonString = '{ "foo": "bar" }'` <-- that is JSON. `var obj = { foo: "bar" }` <-- that's an object. What you have there isn't JSON.

Comment: Sorry for that..but i am using  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)); to convert it into JSON

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
    var idToDelete = 1;
    this.car = this.cart.filter(item=>item.id !=idToDelete );
```

Comment: Can you please let me know how to use this to delete the element 1 by 1 as of no its deleting it at once.